# invite attendees to public calendar event in exchange web services

Tags: asp.net, exchangewebservices

Obviously in outlook, one is able to create an appointment in a public folder and invite people (including yourself) - i want to replicate this with exchange web services.

i can create an event in my own calendar and invite people and that works fine. if i create an event in a public folder and invite people, in the createitem object the **SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations** must be set to **SendToNone**, otherwise it throws this error:

> Meeting invitations or cancellations cannot be sent for calendar items residing in public folders.

which of course means that no invitations get sent. on this calendar item in outlook, if i click **invite attendees** the names are there that i've put in via the webservice call. i could, for instance, then manually send the invitations from outlook, but of course i want this to be all automated.

should i be doing it this way? it seems crazy that for some reason ews wouldn't allow you to do something you're able to do in outlook...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing a similar task in an application to add holiday to user calendars, but I used appointment instead of calendar, which is created for the current authenticated user and then sent to a specific set of user.

The application is written in C#, but you should be able to translate the idea.

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(getExchangeService());
appointment.Subject = "Test meeting";
appointment.Start = DateTime.Now;
appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);

foreach (String emailAddress in attendees)
{
    appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(emailAddress);
}
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Comment: Changing the event to an appointment still doesn't allow the SendToAllAndSaveCopy for items stored in a public folder.